# local app opening instead of ssh forwarded app over x

Tags: ssh, x-windows

i have a custom install of ubuntu 9.10 - xorg intel and its deps, icewm, xde and swiftfox from the swiftfox repos. I'm trying to start a ssh forwarded session of swiftfox from another system - which has the plain vanilla firefox version in the repos- with ssh -x [ipaddress] and then starting swiftfox from command line. When i start it though, it opens up the local copy of firefox instead of the copy of swiftfox on the other box.

I have NO idea what's wrong...swiftfox dosen't open on the remote box, i am definately on the remote boxes terminal, and there's no way whatsoever it should open a local copy. I'm wondering what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 'feature' of Firefox - it detects that you have an existing process and passes the URL to that process, rather than spawning a new instance.

Starting firefox with `firefox -no-remote` tells Firefox to start a second instance; as described on [mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile) you'll need to create a second profile to use instead of the default (Firefox isn't designed to have two processes updating the profile at the same time, so the second instance will refuse to start when it detects that the first instance is using the default profile already)

Comment: Fantastic. It had me baffled a while, but it works as it should.